# SQL Dump - Wordpress doesn't recognize tables imported

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've been trying hard to migrate a Wordpress project and after a thousand attempts, this is the closest I got. I notice that the tables I imported from my previous project are the ones that Wordpress can't reach. Then I thought it was a matter of adding the "56z7sj5c2a" suffix to the tables I moved. So I executed the code `ALTER TABLE wp_options RENAME TO wp_56z7sj5c2a_options;`, for example. It didn't work. Does anyone have any idea how I establish this link with the new tables? Below the message error after pressing the button "repair and optimize".

```
The wp_56z7sj5c2a_users table is okay.

    Failed to optimize the wp_56z7sj5c2a_users table. Error: Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead

The wp_56z7sj5c2a_usermeta table is okay.

    Failed to optimize the wp_56z7sj5c2a_usermeta table. Error: Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead

The wp_56z7sj5c2a_posts table is not okay. It is reporting the following error: Table 'djt443375729453.wp_56z7sj5c2a_posts' doesn't exist. WordPress will attempt to repair this table…
    Failed to repair the wp_56z7sj5c2a_posts table. Error: Table 'djt443375729453.wp_56z7sj5c2a_posts' doesn't exist

The wp_56z7sj5c2a_comments table is okay.

The wp_56z7sj5c2a_links table is okay.

The wp_56z7sj5c2a_options table is not okay. It is reporting the following error: Table 'djt443375729453.wp_56z7sj5c2a_options' doesn't exist. WordPress will attempt to repair this table…
    Failed to repair the wp_56z7sj5c2a_options table. Error: Table 'djt443375729453.wp_56z7sj5c2a_options' doesn't exist

The wp_56z7sj5c2a_postmeta table is not okay. It is reporting the following error: Table 'djt443375729453.wp_56z7sj5c2a_postmeta' doesn't exist. WordPress will attempt to repair this table…
    Failed to repair the wp_56z7sj5c2a_postmeta table. Error: Table 'djt443375729453.wp_56z7sj5c2a_postmeta' doesn't exist

The wp_56z7sj5c2a_terms table is okay.

The wp_56z7sj5c2a_term_taxonomy table is okay.

The wp_56z7sj5c2a_term_relationships table is okay.

The wp_56z7sj5c2a_termmeta table is okay.

The wp_56z7sj5c2a_commentmeta table is okay.
```

Comment: When migrating WordPress, you never have to manually rename tables. You take your `wp-config.php` along to the new host, edit it and change the database name, username, and password to what you created (or got) on the new host and import the SQL dump. The table prefix remains the same. Next, you adapt the site URL to the new host. That's it.

Comment: After importing the SQL Dump, I try to adapt the URL via Putty and it returns me this message: `Error: This does not seem to be a WordPress installation.
Pass --path=`path/to/wordpress` or run `wp core download`.`

Comment: Try `cd path/to/your/wordpress/` before and run it without the `--path` argument. Then, use `wp search-replace your-old-host.net new-domain-name.net`.

Comment: I'm close! I found everything in the wp-config. The only this that is not working now is the password and user name. Do I have to do something about that after migration?

Comment: I was missing the user and user meta tabs! Thx anyway